# How can I make macOS respect HOSTALIASES environment variable?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, hosts

According to the [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/gethostbyname.3.html), setting `HOSTALIASES` will make a process look in that file for hostnames instead of `/etc/hosts`.

However when I tested this with `ping` and a replacement hostfile, the replacement never got used, only `/etc/hosts` (according to `fs_usage`) - I have also seen similar complaints online.

Is there a way to get a process to respect `HOSTALIASES` or otherwise use a different hosts file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The man page that you referenced is *very old* (ancient) - it's from 1995.  Looking at the man page for `gethostbyname` on a machine running El Capitan (2006), that reference is no longer there meaning it's a very good indication that what you are looking for has been deprecated.