# How can I make a process in macOS use a different hosts file without using a chroot jail?

Tags: network, filesystem, hosts

Unlike Linux, we cannot use [HOSTALIASES](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356972/how-can-i-make-macos-respect-hostaliases-environment-variable) env var. I believe it is possible to make a process see a different hosts file if I put it in a chroot jail, but I don't want to have to do that for this process. Is there another way to do this in macOS?

Comment: Does it need to be native? What about using a Docker contained app instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to accomplish in the end, but have you considered using `dnsmasq`? See e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@kharysharpe/automatic-local-domains-setting-up-dnsmasq-for-macos-high-sierra-using-homebrew-caf767157e43)

Comment: @Asmus do you know if there is a way to restrict dnsmasq to only be visible to a single process? E.g. process A uses the normal hosts file, but process B uses what is in dnsmasq?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure; macOS tends to be very odd about DNS lookups :-/. Could you given a specific example for such a process (terminal command / app / webtraffic)?

Comment: Addendum: would it be a problem to reroute the traffic on a per-use basis (i.e. switching to a different DNS configuration only while using this process)? Or would it need to be permanent?

Comment: @Asmus I don't want it to be permanent, only for that instance of the process. However I do want other processes to simultaneously use the "original" configuration and not the one the process is using. The process I want use the temporary configuration is `socat`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clue about `socat`; from what I just google'd it appears that you might be able to directly give it an IP address instead of FQDN, thus skipping DNS? Maybe you should edit this question // post another about the specific task you want `socat` to accomplish, or consider using a Docker or other virtualised OS, as @slm suggested.